# Postgresql on Windows : postmaster.pid remains and prevents restart if the service has crashed

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, postgresql

I have experienced an annoying problem with Postgresql 9.1.1 x64 running as a Windows service on Windows 2008 R2.

The Postgres service crashed for an unknown reason and it left a `postmaster.pid` file on disk which prevents the service from restarting.

Is there a way to configure the creation of this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a safety feature - on Windows the Postgres server uses its PID file as a lock to prevent you from starting more than one postmaster pointing at the same data directory (a quick and easy way to destroy your database).
You should not be looking for ways to bypass this functionality.

If Postgres has actually exited you can remove the PID file and restart it.
You should also be examining your Postgres error logs to find out *why* the server crashed, and addressing that issue.

Comment: Yeah. Specifically, the postmaster has no way to be sure that all the backends of the crashed database server have exited. It doesn't know what their process IDs were and they could've been re-used anyway. It relies on the administrator to make sure any `postgres.exe` backends from that cluster that survived the crash are killed before it's restarted. It'd be nice to make this automatic, but it's also surprisingly difficult.

Comment: @CraigRinger Only because Windows lacks a SysV shared memory work-alike :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 : Is this tied to the process per connection model of PostgreSQL on Windows ? I'm trying to understand how we could end up with several postmaster pointing to the same data directory on Windows (Especially while running as a Windows Service).

Comment: @CraigRinger : I do not know about SysV, but Windows has Memory Mapped Files to deal with inter process communication.

Comment: @voretaq7 While I think the Unix worse is better approach is better and you should just write a lock file on Window, [you can use a mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3x8b09y(v=vs.71).aspx). I've never done it in unmanaged code, but [I've used a pattern similar to this in C#](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html)

Comment: @voretaq7 Now of course its a shortcoming of postgres if it doesn't try to delete the file or enumerate its locks, unless that's a safety feature to force you to manually examine a possible corrupt database.

Comment: @omatrot It has to do with the way Postgres on Unix uses SysV shared memory as a giant mutex ([see here](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2012/06/absurd-shared-memory-limits.html), 3rd paragraph) - I don't know of any shared-memory system other than SysV that provides this because it doesn't really seem useful...unless you're Postgres :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 After several hours of analysis, I could tell that in my case, pg_ctl (hosting the Windows Service) has exited unexpectedly, leaving "ophanned" postgres.exe processes. So Windows tried to restart the service because we told him to do so, while the database server was still running fine :-(. Bad Idea. Instead, we need to run a program that will stop the database cluster before resarting the Windows Service.